# How can I install google/protobuf via composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, php-extension

I am trying to install Protobuf PHP extension in my php project as per the documentation given in https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php requirements section in readme file.

It gives me following error when I try to install the package via `composer require google/protobuf`.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-protobuf * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's protobuf
> extension.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - D:\xampp\php\php.ini
> You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
> Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-protobuf` to temporarily ignore these
> required extensions.

Can anyone guide me to installation process of this extension ?

Comment: "Install or enable PHP's protobuf extension" - anything unclear about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I have downloaded gRPC dll file and added extension to php.ini file, so in the same way i was trying to download dll file for protobuf from https://pecl.php.net/package/protobuf but i couldn't find it. So without dll file how can i add protobuf extension to php.ini file. Installing with composer is done with --ignore-platform-req=ext-protobuf but it doesnot help.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- remove `ext-protobuf` from the `require` part of your `composer.json`

or

- add `--ignore-platform-req=ext-protobuf` to the require command when installing (as shown in the error message you are actually quoting).

Since you are installing a PHP implementation for protobuf, it makes sense removing the extension as a requirement.